# Segmentation fault when attempting to malloc arrays inside pointer to struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to allocate memory for an array inside a struct like this one:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        int a;
        int *b;
    } MyStruct;
```

I have a function to initialize the struct like this one:

```
    void init( MyStruct * myStruct, int size )
    {
        myStruct = malloc( sizeof( MyStruct ) );
        myStruct->a = size;
        myStruct->b = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
    }
```

But when I try to allocate memory for the fields inside the array b, I get the segmentation fault error

```
    int main( void )
    {
        int i, size = 5;
        MyStruct *myStruct;
        init( myStruct, size );

        for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            myStruct->b[i] = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); //fails here
            myStruct->b[i] = i*i;
        }
    }
```

I tried searching over and over, but I was not able to solve this problem.
Someone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter passing in c is call-by-value, so the memory allocated in your `init` function is never assigned to the `myStruct` Pointer variable in `main` but only to its copy that is passed into `init`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you've already allocated five "slots" to put ints in there, so why would you need to call `malloc` again inside the loop? Second, there's no reason to create a pointer to `MyStruct`. So, third, there's no need to allocate memory for the whole structure.

```
void init( MyStruct * myStruct, int size )
{
    myStruct->a = size;
    myStruct->b = malloc(size * sizeof( int ));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, size = 5;
    MyStruct myStruct;
    init( &myStruct, size );

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        myStruct.b[i] = i*i;
    }

    free(myStruct.b);

    return 0;
}
```